# Grails Functional Testing - grailsApplication.config is null within controllers and services

Tags: grails, functional-testing

Grails 1.3.5

I've written a handful of functional tests and I'm running into issues when my controllers and services reference configuration data via grailsApplication.config.  It is always coming back null, so it errors out.

I know there is a mockConfig for unit tests.  But how do I get the config to get wired up for functional tests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the hack that I have done for a while, there might be a better way though

```
def filePath = new File('grails-app/conf/Config.groovy').toURL()
def config = new ConfigSlurper(System.properties.get('grails.env')).parse(filePath)
ConfigurationHolder.config = config
```

Answer (score 13):

You need to construct the grails app -- as it is not injected by default.

```
youService.grailsApplication = new org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication()
```

"DefaultGrailsApplication" by it's default configuration will look for Config as the config class.