# Trouble getting grailsApplication reference from integration test

Tags: grails

I'm using Grails 1.2.1 and trying to write an integration test for one of my service classes.  The service  method i want to test is ...

```
class UtilityService {

boolean transactional = false

def grailsApplication

def isAuthorizedHost(String hostIpAddr) {
    // Simple validation
    if (hostIpAddr == null || hostIpAddr.length() == 0)
        return false;
    //
    def allowedDomains = grailsApplication.config.proxy.allowedDomains
...
```

but when writing my integration test, I'm unable to get a non-null reference to the grailsApplication object ...

```
class UtilityServiceTests extends GrailsUnitTestCase {

def grailsApplication


void testIsAuthorizedHost() {
    def utilityService = new UtilityService()
    utilityService.grailsApplication = grailsApplication
    def ret = utilityService.isAuthorizedHost("127.0.0.1")
    assertTrue( ret )
}
```

Here is the error.  How do I get the reference? - Dave

Cannot get property 'config' on null object

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'config' on null object
at com.nna.tool.proxy.Utility.UtilityService.isAuthorizedHost(UtilityService.groovy:26)
at com.nna.tool.proxy.Utility.UtilityService$isAuthorizedHost.call(Unknown Source)
at com.nna.tool.proxy.Utility.UtilityServiceTests.testIsAuthorizedHost(UtilityServiceTests.groovy:20)

Answer (score 2):

See the answer here.  It might also work in your situation. You can just put that code in the tests setup() method...

[Grails Functional Testing - grailsApplication.config is null within controllers and services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217276/grails-functional-testing-grailsapplication-config-is-null-within-controllers-a)

Answer (score 1):

I think the grailsApplication property is only available in the controller and views, for a service

Try `ApplicationHolder.application.config.proxy.allowedDomains` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be running the integration tests as grails tests not jUnit.

Answer (score 1):

[Constructing grailsApp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20418412/432903) using `DefaultGrailsApplication` would work.

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication

class UtilityServiceTests extends GrailsUnitTestCase {
    def grailsApplication = new DefaultGrailsApplication()

    void testIsAuthorizedHost() {
        def utilityService = new UtilityService()
        utilityService.grailsApplication = grailsApplication
        def ret = utilityService.isAuthorizedHost("127.0.0.1")
        assertTrue( ret )
     }
}
```

#### References

[grails-core / grails-core / src / main / groovy / org / codehaus / groovy / grails / commons / DefaultGrailsApplication.java](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-core/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/DefaultGrailsApplication.java#L103)