# how to mock grailsApplication.getDomainClass(domain.getClass().name)?.clazz

Tags: grails

In my service, the grailsApplication instance is auto injected and it is used to look up the domain name as follows:

```
grailsApplication.getDomainClass(domain.getClass().name)?.clazz
```

How to mock this in the unit test. So far, i have been doing something like:

```
def getDomainClass = {
                assert null
            }
def grailsApplication  = [getDomainClass: getDomainClass]
service.grailsApplication = {grailsApplication as GrailsApplication}
```

However, this doesn't work. It appears, we are getting following error:

```
interface org.springframework.validation.Errors
```

Any suggestions how to mock it? Thank You

Comment: Which version of Grails are you using? For Grails 2.0 and above you can use `@TestFor` which mocks `grailsApplication` for you. Refer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845975/grailsapplication-access-in-grails-unit-test) for details.

Comment: Thank you dmahaptro. It is 2.1.2 and you right. It is mocked. Thank You