# List all Controllers in an Integration test?

Tags: grails, groovy

In one of my integration tests, I need to get a list of all the controllers

In a gsp I can use:

```
${grailsApplication.controllerClasses.sort { it.fullName }
```

But I cannot use this method inside an integration test.

I am using Grails 1.3.7

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7811802/6509  Not sure what version of Grails you're using...

Comment: I am using grails 1.3.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the grailsApplication to get to all Domain classes or Controller classes (as well as probably other artifact types I'm unaware of).

```
Class IntegrationTests {

    def grailsApplication

    @Test
    void something() {
        def controllers = grailsApplication.getArtefacts("Controller")
    }
}
```

http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/GrailsApplication.html#getArtefacts(java.lang.String)